# Updating same id with different quantity (only updating the id that comes first)

Tags: php, mysql, updates, inventory-management

I am new into a database, I am developing an inventory management, I have four  tables, two for `purchase` and `purchase_detail`. And two other for `sale` and `sale_detail`.

This image is my `purchase_detail` table 
[image]
and this is the code for inserting new purchase and it works fine.

```
$sql_insert_sale = "INSERT INTO 
purchase(recipt_no,date,total,vat,totalwithvat) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? ,?, 
?)";
            $query = $dbh->prepare($sql_insert_sale);
            $query->bindParam(1, $recipt_no, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(2, $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(3, $price_all, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(4, $vat_all, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(5, $total_all, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
            $lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
            if ($lastInsertId) {
            $sql_insert_purchase = "INSERT INTO 
 purchase_detail(purchase_id, product_id,vat,price,quantity,amount) "
             . "VALUES ( :purchase_id 
,:product_id,:vat,:price,:quantity,:amount)";
                for($i=0;$i<count($partnumber);$i++) {
                    $data=array(
                                 ':purchase_id'=> $lastInsertId,
                                 ':product_id'=> $id[$i],
                                 ':vat'=> $vat[$i], 
                                 ':price'=> $amount[$i],
                                 ':quantity'=> $quantity[$i],
                                 ':amount'=> $total[$i]
                                );
                     $statement = $dbh->prepare($sql_insert_purchase);
                     if($statement->execute($data)){
                         echo "Successfull";
                     }else{
                         print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
                     }
```

and this is my `sale_detail` table
[image]

I have a problem with `sale` table, when updating the `quantity` in the `purchase_detail` table. As you can see we have same product with different quantity, when I make a new sale it always updates the only quantity of the row with the `product_id` that comes first. Below is the code for making new sale

```
$sql_insert_sale = "INSERT INTO 
  sale(recipt_no,cus_name,date,total)VALUES ( ?,?, ?, ? )";
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql_insert_sale);
        $query->bindParam(1, $recipt_no, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(2, $cus_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(3, $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(4, $total_all, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
                $lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
                if ($lastInsertId) {
                    $sql_insert_sale = "INSERT INTO 
 sale_detail(sale_id, product_id,vat,price_vat,quantity,amount) "
 . "VALUES ( :sale_id,:product_id,:vat,:price_vat,:quantity,:amount)";
                 for($i=0;$i<count($partnumber);$i++) {
                    $data=array(
                                 ':sale_id'=> $lastInsertId,
                                 ':product_id'=> $id[$i],
                                 ':vat'=> $vat[$i], 
                                 ':price_vat'=> $price[$i],
                                 ':quantity'=> $quantity[$i],
                                 ':amount'=> $total[$i]
                                );
                     $statement = $dbh->prepare($sql_insert_sale);
                     if($statement->execute($data)){
                         $sql_update_purchase="UPDATE purchase_detail 
                     INNER JOIN product "
                                 . 
                  "on(purchase_detail.product_id=product.product_id) "
                                 . "SET 
      purchase_detail.quantity=purchase_detail.quantity-$quantity[$i]"
                                 . " WHERE 
    purchase_detail.product_id=$id[$i] and product.product_id=$id[$i]";
    $statement_update=$dbh->prepare($sql_update_purchase);
                         if($statement_update->execute())
```

Please, tell what's wrong with my code, I really appreciate your help. I am nearly close to my deadline for finishing it.

Comment: This code is not too bad for *"I am new into a database"*. You are using PDO with prepared statements, except `purchase_detail.quantity=purchase_detail.quantity-$quantity[$i]" . " WHERE purchase_detail.product_id=$id[$i] and product.product_id=$id[$i]";` This could be improved.

Comment: What is `purchase_detail`, what is `sale_detail`. Are you confusing names or speaking about different tables?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone thanks, it's not working as expected. It only updating the id that  comes first. What I want is to update sum of the quantities for the same id.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone they are different tables, purchase and purchase_detail for the products we buy. and sale and sale_detail for products we sell.

Comment: Oh I see, it's hard to read the floating text.

Comment: Please check if my edits are correct, especially `product_id`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "we have same product with different quantity"? There should be product master data with unique ids. Then there is transaction data like purchase and sale. In a normalized DB there's one data row per each product storing the amount in stock. Each transaction has its own amount which will update the master data. Everything else is related by joins. What are you trying to achieve? You show only 2 of 4 tables.

Comment: I have two more table which are purchase(purchase_id, recipt_ no, date, total, vat, totalwithvat ) and sale(sale_id, recipt_no, cus_name, date, total). if you look at purchase_detail table, we have same product_id that we bought more than two times with different quantity. What is want is when selling new product the quantities in purchase_detail table should be updated.

Comment: Why should purchase be updated? It looks as there were multiple **transactions** in purchase. So the current stock would be the initial stock + sum of all purchases - sum of all sells. You should insert a new purchase and you might want to update a stock column of the product or product detail table. There should be exactly one distinct stock quantity per product in database. You might have to restructure the DB. Or you should explain the complete structure of the DB.

Comment: Isn't there any `product` table holding the name, desciption, article number, current price and stock quantity? If not, the DB is broken by design. Distinguish between master data and transaction data.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone thanks, should I add a new stock table, which includes quantity, product_id and purchase_id. Does this solve my problem?

Comment: product table is includes(name, part number, description) it does not includes quantity and price. these two fields I added to purchase_detail table.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Consider you buy 100 pieces at $10 per pc today. Tomorrow you get 100 more at a price of only $5. Then you sell 10 pieces. You cannot substract 10 from both purchases, however, from which purchase would you do? When calculating e.g. the tax, you need to know how much you purchased at which price at which time. You may not fake the purchase data.

Comment: What you mean by which purchase? I am now really good at databases, the tax is not calculated, it is fixed.

Comment: Each, the product, purchase and sell table need to have a price and quantity. product.quantity is the stock, product.price the current sell price wich will be used, when an insert into sell is done. This can vary from time to time. The transactions done will not change. If a customer gives something back, you need to know at which price he purchased the product. You also want to document how much at which price you have purchased at which time. The assistent should enter the price of the bill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188772/discussion-between-quasimodos-clone-and-dosti).